# POST request is not working in REST API for Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, post, laravel-5.4

I have tried to send some values using post method in REST API Tool.
I have used Laravel version 5.4.
I have tried the following code

### Route File:

```
Route::post('ws-register',array('uses' => 'AppController@doRegister'));
```

### Controller File

```
public function doRegister() {
    $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users', 
        'password' => 'required|alpha_num|min:6|max:15'
    );
    $messages = array('alpha_spaces' => 'Name must be alphanumeric');
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $error = $validator->errors()->all(':message');

        $response['message'] = $error[0];
        $response['code'] = false;
    } else {
            $user = new Users;

            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();

            $response['user_id'] = $user->id;
            $response['message'] = "Success";
            $response['code'] = true;
        }
    }
    return Response::json($response);
}
```

While calling through REST API POST Method, I am getting "500: Internal Server Error" as response.
Can anyone help me out to find what I have done wrong?

Comment: The alphanumeric validation is `alpha_num` isn't it? Also messages should be in the format `field.validationrule => message`

Comment: @apokryfos yes its an alphanumeric validation

Comment: Yes, you have `alphaNum`, shouldn't it be `alpha_num`?

Comment: ok even if i the change that validation, error remains the same. The function itself is not getting called @apokryfos

Comment: In that case you should check the error logs (either apache log or laravel log).

Comment: The controller funvtion itself is not getting called through POST Method @apokryfos

Comment: I have checked on PHP error log, apche error log and laravel log. No recent errors are recorded @apokryfos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135592/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-apokryfos).

Comment: still the same error @Kumar

Comment: "tokenmismatchexception in verifycsrftoken.php line 67 in laravel" this is the error, i am getting while checking through REST API @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are having `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php` error, as was written in question comments.

As stated in `app/Http/Kernel.php`, VerifyCsrfToken middleware is applied to all routes in `routes/web.php`. But it is not applied to `routes/api.php`

If you are making API request, may be it is better to place your route in `routes/api.php` file. Then, when making API call, make sure to add `/api` prefix to your request, like this:

```
POST http://example.app/api/ws-register
```

But if you still want to to keep your route in `routes/web.php`, think of adding CSRF-protection. More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

Comment: i have tried using like this http://example.com/api/ws-register , its showing Error 302 @Petr Reshetin

Comment: @ArunKumar 302 is http redirect response. To what location does it redirect? You may see it in response header, more info [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/http-302-error)

Comment: in the response header, I am getting the following                                     Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 13:00:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 PHP/7.0.8 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Location: http://localhost:8888/website/public/login
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 60
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 58
Content-Length: 444
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: @ArunKumar so it redirects to login page, so may be need to remove some auth middleware. you may check existing middlewares that apply to your route by `php artisan route:list --path=ws-register`. So make sure your route is outside `Route::middleware('auth:api')`

Comment: I am new to laravel. can you pls explain little more clear @PetrReshetin

Comment: api.php file                                                                                                                                            use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::post('ws-register',array('uses' => 'AppController@doRegister'));

Comment: lets go to chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135960/laravel

Comment: on api.php file i have given the above lines @PetrReshetin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136425/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-petr-reshetin).